# How to preserve encoded numpy array on disk?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of numbers as follows:

```
array([[ 0.00365172, -0.01862929,  0.00739219, ..., -0.05520727,
        -0.00388453, -0.00591132],
       [ 0.00084692, -0.0177305 ,  0.00618157, ..., -0.05275924,
        -0.00323982, -0.00107789],
       [ 0.01276451, -0.00361472,  0.0008607 , ...,  0.00464235,
         0.00075972,  0.00700309]], dtype=float32)
```

What is the most efficient way to store this on disk such that each array item is encoded in some text label as follows:

```
array(['LabelA'   
       'LabelB',
       'LabelC'])
```

In other words, LabelA, LabelB and LabelC are string representations of the corresponding number vectors. My goal is to store this kind of array in a human readable format and I don't really care about reading the numerical values, yet preserving their one-to-one relationship with the corresponding unique labels.

Is something like this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: Yes @Divakar, I still need to run few more tests especially since I need to rebuild the original array from the Labels but this approach seems like it will work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are trying to assign labels to each row based on uniqueness among themselves. So, you can use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with its `axis` argument to pack each row as one *item* and `return_inverse` for ID-ing each such item based on their uniqueness, like so -

```
In [42]: a = np.array([[3,5,8,2],[4,1,5,2],[3,5,8,2]])

In [43]: unique_ids = np.unique(a,axis=0, return_inverse=1)[1]

In [44]: unique_ids
Out[44]: array([0, 1, 0])

In [45]: ['Label'+str(i) for i in unique_ids]
Out[45]: ['Label0', 'Label1', 'Label0']
```

For upto `26` unique labels, we can surely use `capital letters` -

```
In [50]: import string

In [51]: ['Label'+string.uppercase[i] for i in unique_ids]
Out[51]: ['LabelA', 'LabelB', 'LabelA']
```